# Multiple validate_doc_update functions in CouchDB design documents. Any good practices?

Tags: javascript, validation, couchdb

After reading this paragraph in the CouchDB Definitive Guide ([here](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/validation.html)):

> If you have multiple design documents, each with a validate_doc_update function, all of those functions are called upon each incoming write request. Only if all of them pass does the write succeed. The order of the validation execution is not defined. Each validation function must act on its own.

I'm wondering if there is any good practice to deal with multiple validate_doc_update function ?

I mean: Is it better to create only one design document with a validate_doc_update field or having several smaller ones?

In the first case, one can be sure that none of the validation functions will interfere with another, but the function may become very large if a lot of controls are needed.

On the other side, several smaller functions may be easier for reading purposes and evolutions, but one have to be sure of the purpose of each function and not mess with other ones.

Plus, what's the point of letting each design document hold a validate function? Storing one in a view document seems a bit dirty for instance, but creating several design documents just for the intent of holding one small validation function doesn't seems very clever to me either.

What do you think?

I may have missed something, that's the point of my question, is there any good practices about the management of multiple validate_doc_update function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note, I wrote the quoted paragraph.

In general, I'm seeing a 1:1 correlation between applications and design docs. Everything a single application needs should be in one design document. Bigger applications may want to rely on multiple design docs for various reasons (like different groups of views), but in general, one design doc per app is a good rule of thumb.

Now, you may have multiple applications per database. E.g. a CMS: one application could be the public facing CMS viewing app and another one would be the admin interface. You want to keep them separate because, well, they are two distinct apps that operate on the same data and keeping them separate is a good organisational idea. Different security mechanisms apply, so you have two validation functions that do implement what is applicable for the respective app.

The quoted paragraphis the definition of the case where you do have (for whatever reason) have more than one design document per database. It explains what to expect. It is not meant as a guideline how to split things up. Go with the one design doc per app rule of thumb and you're good most of the time.

Comment: +1. I wonder how different things would be if "design document" had been called "app" since the beginning. Maybe "app" isn't a good word for it, but "design document" doesn't mean much to most users. (And while I'm changing history, I'd just call documents "records.")

Comment: I agree with @jhs that "design document" might be confusing, especially at the beginning. What could have been done is create different "types" of design documents dedicated to something, for instance a type "auth" which must contain a field "validate_doc_update" and forbid something else like "views" and a type "view" containing a field "views" and no "validate_doc_update". Actually this can be done with a validation function but a built-in stuff would be easier to organize all this I think. The good point of not doing so is letting the user manage its documents as he wishes I suppose ?

Comment: Yes, CouchDB is relaxed. If you wish to enforce your own policy, you can and should! However I usually start with one big design document to do everything, then I split into more if there is a very obvious reason. For example, I've used
 Erlang to implement filter functions since they are faster.

Answer (score 6):

I know there has already been an answer selected, but I will at least throw out my practices regarding the matter as an alternative.

I have decided against just building pure CouchApps, at least for the time-being. (I have decided on Node.JS as my new middleware layer) With that in mind, I get a lot more flexibility out of CouchDB Design Documents.

I have moved toward having a separate Design Document for each entity in my database. As a result, each design document contains it's own views, validation functions, update handlers, etc. In response to your question, each validation function deals with only 1 entity in my database, which makes it more focused and easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks. It's also the aim of this question. See how people deal with it.

Comment: Do you mean a design document for each "type" of record/document in the database? That's cool. CouchDB is relaxed. Also NodeJS is my personal favorite way to use CouchDB. Can't argue there, although I usually use it as an external processor, reacting to `_changes` results rather than intercepting queries.